# Software for automatic building floorplan calculation / drawing (packing problem)

Tags: structural-engineering, cad, building-design

An apartment yield analysis is a set of draft drawings in which the optimum residential apartment layout and resultant yield is calculated for a given building site, taking into account development constraints such as apartment area sizes, floor-to-space ratios, building setbacks, solar exposure, internal corridor widths etc.

This bulk of this is done by an architect / draftsperson manually; the problem is not trivial and it can take man-hours of trial and error to approach an optimal layout.

My view is that once most of the constraints are established, it falls into the 'packing problem' domain that computers are useful at attacking.

Is there any service or CAD software component that wholly or partly automates the packing of such shapes and produces the drawings for a building or individual floorplans?

Comment: Have you done a search for "excel packing problem"? Seem to be some very interesting results just in the first few...

Comment: Optimality of packing problems can not be proven.

Comment: @SolarMike sorry, I edited to clarify I'm looking for drawings produced also, not just calculations

Comment: I find it unlikely this tool as you envision exists. Its not so much that its impossible. But rather it is a result of the landscape in architecture, while this is slowly changing, its somehow resistant  to automation. This means that its not a appealing target, hell you dont even use constrains based cad applications yet. I mean even simple analysis tools like automatic checking of door directions for security groups isnt used, and this is trivial to program.

Answer (score 0):

That's called architecture and no there is no software to replace the job of an architect. There are many tools to make this process easier from conception to preliminary modeling through finished working drawings.

But the same way you can not have a word processor write a novel, there is no software to design architectural projects. That actually leaves the process free to skills and experience and artistic flare of the designer.

That doesn't mean that highly technical or specialty function spaces like hospital ORs or say refinery control rooms or some military buildings don't have prescribed standard plans and specs.